# Conexión a mongodb es rechazada a pesar de que está corriendo el servicio

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, express, mongoose, connection

Buen día a todos, mi problema consiste en que a pesar de que el servicio mongod en mi ubuntu 20.04 está corriendo pero al querer conectarme a mongodb a través de node js me lanza un error y es el siguiente

MongooseServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27027

Y los detalles:

```js
TopologyDescription {
     type: 'Single',
     setName: null,
     maxSetVersion: null,
     maxElectionId: null,
     servers: Map { 'localhost:27027' => [ServerDescription] },
     stale: false,
     compatible: true,
     compatibilityError: null,
     logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null,
     heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
     localThresholdMS: 15,
     commonWireVersion: null }
```

Ya he intentado reiniciar tanto el servicio como mi computadora y aun nada, será que debo cambiar el puerto del servicio?
Agradecería su ayuda en esto.

Comment: El puerto TCP por defecto de MongoDB es `27017` y en tu conexión veo que usas `27027`. Si no has cambiado el puerto TCP de Mongo, el problema es que estás tratando de conectarte al puerto equivocado. Revisa eso y comenta el resultado. Saludos

Comment: Efectivamente amigo era un problema con el puerto, lo realice nuevamente y me funciono, muchas gracias por la ayuda! y saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

puedes usar mongoose  --> `npm install mongoose -save`

luego:

```
'use strict'
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var app = require('./app');
var port = process.env.PORT || 3977;

//mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/notos', (err, res) => {
    if (err) {
        throw err;
    }
    else {
        console.log('la base esta corriendo correctamente...');
        app.listen(port, function () {
            console.log("el servidor del api rest activo en http://localhost:" + port)

            let now = new Date();
            console.log('La fecha actual es', now);
        });
    }
});
```

acá un link con ejemplos:
https://code.tutsplus.com/es/articles/an-introduction-to-mongoose-for-mongodb-and-nodejs--cms-29527

ejemplo para guardar un usuario:

```
            //guardar usuario
            user.save((err, userStored) => {
                if (err) {
                    console.log('error 500: ' + err.message)
                    res.status(500).send({ message: err.message })
                } else {
                    if (!userStored) {
                        console.log('error 404: No se ha registrado el usuario')
                        res.status(404).send({ message: 'No se ha registrado el usuario' })
                    } else {
                        console.log('200 usuario registrado.')
                        sendEmail(user, newPassword)
                        res.status(200).send({ user: userStored })
                    }
                }
            })
```

Comment: El OP ya está usando Mongoose.